# I have a problem with static files in django

Tags: javascript, python, django

I cant refrence to contexts in js

**HTML**

```
{% load static%}
{%block content%}
    <div id="backSign" , style="display: none;">go to lesions</div>
    <ol id="list"></ol>
{% endblock content%}
{% block extrajs %}
<script src="{% static 'assets/js/idioms.js'%}"></script>
{% endblock extrajs %}
```

**JS**

```
const Data = '{{ data|escapejs }}'
console.log(Data)
```

output : "{{ data|escapejs }}"

when i put js in script tag it works but when i refrence the place its return this : {{ data|escapejs }}